# Cocos2d Sprite 3D position

Tags: c++, 2d, graphics, software-engineering, cocos2d-x

When I set a position3D for a Sprite in cocos2dx, it render two times the same sprite, i took a screenshot:

[image]

I set the position3D because i want to use the Z position the give an effect of distance, but its rendering these two sprites in the lower left corner, how can I fix that?

Here is my code in .h:

```
cocos2d::Sprite* mySprite;
cocos2d::Sprite* mySprite2;
cocos2d::Camera* camera;
```

Here i my code in cpp:

```
bool HelloWorld::init()
{

if ( !Layer::init() )
{
    return false;
}


auto s = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
camera = Camera::createPerspective(60, (GLfloat)s.width / s.height, 1, 100);

camera->setRotation3D(Vec3(0, 0, 0));

this->addChild(camera);
mySprite2 = Sprite::create("idle1.png");
mySprite2->setPosition3D(Vec3(5, 0, -41));
mySprite2->getTexture()->setAliasTexParameters();

this->addChild(mySprite2, 2);

mySprite = Sprite::create("idle1.png");
mySprite->setPosition3D(Vec3(-5, 0, -81));
mySprite->getTexture()->setAliasTexParameters();

this->addChild(mySprite, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the camera user to something other than DEFAULT because the DEFAULT camera is used for things like UI, Menus and is rendered last.

```
// Camera
auto s = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
auto camera = Camera::createPerspective(60, (GLfloat) s.width / s.height, 1, 1000);

// set parameters for camera
camera->setPosition3D(Vec3(0, 400, 400));
camera->lookAt(Vec3(0, 0, 0), Vec3(0, 1, 0));
camera->setCameraFlag(CameraFlag::USER1);
this->addChild(camera); //add camera to the scene
```

So when you create a new camera the deafult camera is set to DEFAULT, and the new camera is also set to DEFAULT initially. So set it to USER1.